# Makefile construction

Tags: c, makefile

Hi I am trying to construct a makefile for a c program named `main.c` (assume that it just prints `Hello World` to the screen) when typing `make` in the terminal it generate an executable called `main` but I don't want it to be `main`. I want to define the name of the executable in the terminal.for example when typing:

```
make firstTest
```

I want it generate an executable named `firstTest` and when typing:

```
make secondTest
```

I want it generate an executable named `secondTest`. My makefile code is:

```
all: main

main: main.o
    gcc -g -Wall -o main main.o 

main.o: main.c
    gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c 

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    rm -f *.o main
```

How do I need to change it in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: I also would like to note that you can assume that firstTest and secondtests exist.

Answer (score 2):

A [last-resort default rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Last-Resort) can do what you want:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: main

%: main.o
    gcc -g -Wall -o $@ $<

main.o: main.c
    gcc -g -Wall -c -o $@ $<

clean: 
    rm -f *.o main

Makefile:;
```

Note the `Makefile:;` apparently useless rule. It is essential to tell make that the Makefile itself shall not be rebuilt with the last-resort default rule. Note also that the `clean` target cannot guess which executable names you decided to use and cannot delete them.

Demo:

```
$ ls
main.c  Makefile
$ make
make
gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -g -Wall -o main main.o
$ ls
main  main.c  main.o  Makefile
$ make clean
rm -f *.o main
$ ls
main.c  Makefile
$ make firstTest
gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -g -Wall -o firstTest main.o
$ ls
firstTest  main.c  main.o  Makefile
$ make clean
rm -f *.o main
$ ls
firstTest  main.c  Makefile
$ make secondTest
gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -g -Wall -o secondTest main.o
$ ls
firstTest  main.c  main.o  Makefile  secondTest
$ make clean
rm -f *.o main
$ ls
firstTest  main.c  Makefile  secondTest
```

Answer (score 0):

The `make` command generates the files that are dependencies of the `all` target. This is why the generated file is called `main`.

When you execute the command `make`, all files that are dependencies of the `all` target are generated. However when you have a command like `make first`. The make will start from the target `first` and execute the commands that will generate it.

So `first` must be a target in the Makefile.

As far as I am concerned the only way to change the name of the generated file is to change it in the Makefile like `gcc -g -Wall -o firstTest main.o`

or in the commandline by `make; mv main firstTest`